# issue with Google_Service_Exception gmail api php

Tags: codeigniter-3, gmail-api

there is a **Google_Service_Exception** error 404

```
Message: Global HTTP Batch endpoint is deprecated. See https://g.co/cloud/global-batch-deprecation for info and migration steps.
```

my Gmail inbox can not load using this error

can you help me out of here?

Comment: Are you performing requests to `https://www.googleapis.com/rpc`
`https://content.googleapis.com/rpc` or
`https://clients6.google.com/rpc`? Include your relevant code for suggestions of an aternative approach.

Comment: i got ...{"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse Error","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"parseError","message":"Parse Error"}]}}

Comment: What did you do to get this message? It would be helpful to see your code.

Comment: $client->setUseBatch(true);
                $batch = new Google_Http_Batch($client);

                    $i = 0;

                        $req = $service->users_threads->get($email, $value['id'], ['format' => 'full']);
                        $batch->add($req);
                        $i++;

                    $results = $batch->execute();
                }

Comment: @ziganotschka... i used this code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As announced by Google, [Global HTTP Batch endpoint is deprecated](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html?utm_campaign=ei-jun23&utm_medium=api-error-message&utm_source=shared_proxy)

### You need to change to the API-specific endpoint.

For Gmail API, modify your code from

`$batch = new Google_Http_Batch($client)`

to

`$batch = new Google_Http_Batch($client,false,'https://gmail.googleapis.com')`